# Dynamics CRM 365 WebApi 8.2 AddListMembersList method

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is there any example how to call `AddListMembersList`? I tried with:

```
let data = {
       "MemberIds": [500aa55d-f0c2-e711-80ca-005056bb6cde, 500aa55d-f0c2-e711-80ca-005056bb6cd, 500aa55d-f0c2-e711-80ca-005056bb6cde]
};

http.post(this.baseUrl + 'lists(770aa55d-f0c2-e711-80ca-005056bb6cde)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddListMembersList', data);
```

but I get error:

> "error":{
>        "code":"","message":"Request message has unresolved parameters.","innererror":{
>       "message":"Request message has unresolved parameters.","type":"Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException","stacktrace":"
>   bei
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataRoutingConvention.SelectAction(ODataPath
>   odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup`2
>   actionMap)\r\n bei
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n bei
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n bei
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact answer can be found here: http://butenko.pro/2018/03/01/how-to-add-records-to-marketing-list-using-webapi/

From link adjusted to my example:

```
var data = {
    List: {
        listid: "9DEE7D76-611D-E811-A95B-000D3A1087A0",
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.list"
    },
    Members: [{
        accountid: "6785A521-A2C0-E711-A950-000D3A109280",
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account"
    },
    {
        accountid: "3653A521-A2C0-E711-A950-000D3A109280",
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account"
    }]
};

this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'AddListMembersList', data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call an action - [AddListMembersList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/addlistmemberslist?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9). Syntax would be like:

```
/api/data/v8.2/AddListMembersList
```

I would recommend you to use [CRMRestBuilder](https://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2016/01/crm-rest-builder-2300-now-with-web-api.html) to play around, test & understand.

```
var parameters = {};
var list = {};
list.listid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
list["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.list";
parameters.List = list;
var members1 = {};
members1.contactid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
members1["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact";
parameters.Members = [members1];

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/AddListMembersList", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work. Right answer is when we replace list.primarykeyid with listid and members1.primarykeyid with the real name of the entityId (accointid, contactid ...).